# Using a for loop to find the difference between two time strings (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: java, android, time, for-loop

I need to use a for loop, and arrays, to take two inputs and subtract them (input format `hh:mm:ss`). Then output the difference in a editText. But I can't seem to get to get my code to run.

Sorry if this is a really basic problem. I have spent days looking on the web trying to understand the problem. This is my first attempt at Java.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    end = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnd);
    start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
    diff = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDiff);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalc);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int hh = tot[0];
                int mm = tot[1];
                int ss = tot[2];

            String sGet2 = end.getText().toString(); // end to string
            String sGet1 = start.getText().toString(); // start to string

            String[] erA = sGet2.split(":"); // end string to end array
            String[] srA = sGet1.split(":"); // start string to string array

            for (int i = 0; i < srA.length; i++) {

                inted = Integer.parseInt(erA[i].trim()); 
                intst = Integer.parseInt(srA[i].trim());

                tot[i] = inted - intst;

                if (i == 2) { 
                    String  mt = ":" + mm;
                    String  st = ":" + ss;
                    String  ht = ":" + hh;
                    String tota = mt + st;
                    String total = tota + ht;

                    out = String.format("%4.4s", total);

                    diff.setText(out);

                } else
                    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising your code doesn't work... a lot of it never executes!

```
for (int i = 0; i < srA.length; i++) {
    // bla bla bla
    if (i == 2) { 
        // This code never runs because i is always 0.
    } else
        return;  // What is this doing here!?
}
```

If this is your first attempt at programming then I think you should start with something a little simpler such as a console program. Also use a debugger to step through the code so that you can see how the control flow works.

You might also want to buy a book that teaches Java. There are many good books you can use that start you off with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Great code why return in else part. it terminates the execution when i=0. That is as the for loop starts execution.

first time i value is zero and your condition i==2 fails then it execute else part so it terminaes the for loop. then what is the use of for loop?????

use the below code::

```
String time1 = "22:55:00";
String time2 = "23:05:00";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

difference is in millis you can convert it to any unit or you can use DurationFormatUtils from apache-commons to pretty format it.

```
System.out.println("Duration: "+DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(difference, "HH:mm:ss"));
```

apache commons has really nice utility functions, apache-commons (lang)

Comment: should i take out the if and else statements and put the if code after the for loop? oh and lose the return;

Comment: what exactly you are tryin to do

Comment: I have three EditText's. Two of them are for input(ex. hh:mm:ss) The third one will display the difference when the submit Button is pushed.

Comment: Thank you, I shall give it a go. Thanks for taking the time to post.